# Selenium RC Chrome SSL Issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

When i run the Selenium RC in Chrome it asks for SSL,it keeps on asking even if i click proceed anyway.Is there any workaround available.Is there option for providing chrome template as we provide  firefox profile.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing this 
This is in Ruby

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.secure_ssl = true
```